# How to PHP echo when using multiple quotes

Tags: php, jquery

How should I quote this:

```
<tr onclick="$.colorbox({href:'information1.html'});">
```

When put in an `echo " ";` ?

I have tried this:

```
echo "<tr onclick='$.colorbox({href:'information1.html'});'>";
```

Which shows a Jquery error.

And I tried this:

```
echo "<tr onclick="$.colorbox({href:'information1.html'});">";
```

Which shows a PHP error.

Any workarounds? Thanks

Comment: \ escape charecter use like this `echo "<tr onclick=\"$.colorbox({href:'information1.html'});\">";` to escape

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes symbols:

```
echo '<tr onclick="$.colorbox({href:\"information1.html\"});">'
```

**Note that using inline script is not considered to be a good practice!**

```
echo '<tr class="foo">'
```

In the javascript code:

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
    $.colorbox({ href: "information1.html" });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you gdoron, I will know from now on!

Comment: @pufAmuf. No problem, And try to avoid usage of inline script, it's deprecated...

Answer (score 4):

Simply escape the quotes. Whilst on this subject I feel it important to mention the fact that generally speaking, you should use single quotes for 'code' and double quotes only for displayed strings.

This stems from C standards and keeping this consistent will help you in the future if for example you wanted to implement `gettext()` and translate your website into multiple languages.

```
echo '<tr onclick="$.colorbox({href:\'information1.html\'});\">';
```

Having said that, there's a better way to achieve what you're doing. Give the row an id:

```
<tr id="inforow" />
```

And use jQuery to bind to it's click event when the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inforow").click(function() {
        $.colorbox({href:'information1.html'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Anytime you want to print a string with a quote in it, just use the escape character '\' to ignore the quote as a literal closing quote, like so:

```
echo "<tr onclick=\"$.colorbox({href:'information1.html'});\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
echo "<tr onclick=\"$.colorbox({href:'information1.html'});\">";
```

Comment: Thanks gzg, however I got an error after using your code. I had luck with gdoron's answer, but I really appreciate your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer, I had forgotten the semicolon at the end. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<tr onclick=\"$.colorbox({href:'information1.html'});\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<tr onclick=\"$.colorbox({href:'information1.html'});\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use PHP-methods instead of caring about the quotes

```
echo '<tr onclick="'.
          htmlentities('$.colorbox('.json_encode(array('href'=>'information.html'))).')">';
```

...will always create proper JSON and proper HTML, no matter what characters you use.

Answer (score 1):

NO NEED to quote it.
NO NEED to put in an echo " ";

Just leave it  AS IS:

```
?>
<tr onclick="$.colorbox({href:'information1.html'});">
<?
```

as well as any other HTML.

It's PHP. It's **embedded** in HTML. You can leave PHP mode any time

Comment: Cool, so but what if this data is inside the `mysql_fetch_array( $data ))`. Can I close the php with `?>` and then open it back up again without having to do another select query?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using EOD

```
$string = <<<EOD
"duble quotation" and 'quotation' all enable
EOD;
echo $string;
```