# Jquery modal with ajax content to load onclick not all at once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I am a bit baffled by my situation, I hope you guys could shine a little light on my challenge!

Ok, I have made a query that loads about 1,000 or so names in my database. I successfully made an echo that loads a modal window with the profile details inside of each modal div.

The problem is when I have 1,000 names to populate, it has to build each modal  with the profile details inside and it takes a while to load the page.

I am looking for a better way to retrieve the modal window with an onclick action of some sort, so all the modal windows will not have to be made when the page loads. So maybe just an action that when a user clicks the link, it will load it somehow ?

Here is my code that works, but again -- is loads all the info on each page load:

```
<div  id="myModal_."$pageID"" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <script>
    $("#".$pageID."").load("admin/page1.php?m=".$pageID."");
    </script>
  </div>
</div>

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal_'.$pageID.'">'.$name.'</a>
```

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT

Here is my html I am seeing in firebug -- it isn't loading anything in the modal window ?

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="7"></div>                                                 
    <script>
        $('a[href="#myModal7"]').on('click',function(){
        $("#7").load("admin/page1.php?m=7");
        });
    </script>
</div>

<a href="#myModal7" data-toggle="modal">Name goes here</a>
```

Comment: Are you thinking of a javascript function that could generate the modal HTML on the fly, and then execute the load function?

Comment: Just a better and more efficient way to load these many modal windows??

Comment: Yeah. It would save you from having to load the html for all the pageIDs. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div  id="myModal_."$pageID"" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <script>
           $('a[href="#myModal'.$pageID.'"]').on('click',function(){
               $("#myModal_".$pageID." .modal-body").load("admin/page1.php?m=".$pageID."");
           });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>


<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal'.$pageID.'">'.$name.'</a>
```

Comment: so when I click the link -- then it would load the details in the modal window ?

Comment: i think .. you have different links for different modal's ??

Comment: `$("#".$pageID."")` is that correct id for your modal   ....i think it should be like  `$("#myModal_".$pageID." .modal-body")`

Comment: Having problem getting this to echo in php ? $(\"a[href=\"#myModal'.$row['memberID'].'\"]\").on('click',function(){

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9754707/235710  this would be helpful in echoing your string

Comment: having trouble with this. It isn't loading anything in the modal window ?

Answer (score 1):

This function creates the HTMLonly when users click on a link. The idea is to avoid wasting a lot of time loading HTML that won't be used:

```
$(".modalLink").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($("#myModal_" + id).length == 0) {
        var div1 = $('<div id="myModal_' + id + '" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" />');
        var div2 = $('<div class"modal-body"/>');
        $('body').append(div1);
        div1.append(div2);
    }
    $('#myModal_' + id + ' div').load("admin/page1.php?m=" + id);
    $("#myModal_" + id).modal();
    return false;
});
```

Each link should have the class 'modalLink'and a unique id:

```
<a id="$pageID" class="modalLink" href="#">$name</a>
```

Since I don't know what modal script you're using, I coded it for the  one I found here: http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/. I tested it, and it works as expected.

Comment: Awesome! I am patient! Thanks NINJA!

Comment: I made a number of edits, so if you had trouble, you might want to try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mylink').click(function(){
     $("#".$pageID."").load("admin/page1.php?m=".$pageID."");
});
```

is this what you're looking for?